# Listing all subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Here's how to show all subgroups of $S_4$ in [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/):

```
gap> AllSubgroups(SymmetricGroup(4));
[ Group(()), Group([ (1,2)(3,4) ]), Group([ (1,3)(2,4) ]), Group([ (1,4)(2,3) ]), Group([ (3,4) ]), Group([ (2,3) ]),
  Group([ (2,4) ]), Group([ (1,2) ]), Group([ (1,3) ]), Group([ (1,4) ]), Group([ (2,4,3) ]), Group([ (1,3,2) ]),
  Group([ (1,4,2) ]), Group([ (1,4,3) ]), Group([ (1,4)(2,3), (1,3)(2,4) ]), Group([ (3,4), (1,2)(3,4) ]),
  Group([ (1,4), (1,4)(2,3) ]), Group([ (2,4), (1,3)(2,4) ]), Group([ (1,3,2,4), (1,2)(3,4) ]), Group([ (1,4,3,2), (1,
   3)(2,4) ]), Group([ (1,2,4,3), (1,4)(2,3) ]), Group([ (3,4), (2,4,3) ]), Group([ (1,4), (1,4,3) ]),
  Group([ (2,3), (1,3,2) ]), Group([ (1,2), (1,4,2) ]), Group([ (1,4)(2,3), (1,3)(2,4), (3,4) ]), Group([ (1,2)
  (3,4), (1,3)(2,4), (1,4) ]), Group([ (1,2)(3,4), (1,4)(2,3), (2,4) ]), Group([ (1,4)(2,3), (1,3)(2,4), (2,4,3) ]),
  Group([ (1,4)(2,3), (1,3)(2,4), (2,4,3), (3,4) ]) ]
```

In Mathematica I can display the elements of $S_4$:

```
In[2]:= GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[4]]

Out[2]= {Cycles[{}],Cycles[{{3,4}}],Cycles[{{2,3}}],Cycles[{{2,3,4}}],Cycles[{{2,4,3}}],Cycles[{{2,4}}],Cycles[{{1,2}}],Cycles[{{1,2},{3,4}}],Cycles[{{1,2,3}}],Cycles[{{1,2,3,4}}],Cycles[{{1,2,4,3}}],Cycles[{{1,2,4}}],Cycles[{{1,3,2}}],Cycles[{{1,3,4,2}}],Cycles[{{1,3}}],Cycles[{{1,3,4}}],Cycles[{{1,3},{2,4}}],Cycles[{{1,3,2,4}}],Cycles[{{1,4,3,2}}],Cycles[{{1,4,2}}],Cycles[{{1,4,3}}],Cycles[{{1,4}}],Cycles[{{1,4,2,3}}],Cycles[{{1,4},{2,3}}]}
```

What's a good approach for listing the subgroups in Mathematica?

Comment: Unfortunately, the ClearAll["Global`*"]; FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup",   4}, "Subgroups"] command fails, outputting Missing["NotAvailable"].

Comment: The command
`FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 4}, "Information"]`
says, in particular,

"The symmetric group S_n of degree n is the group of all permutations on n symbols. S_n is therefore a permutation group of order n! 
and contains as subgroups every group of order n". Hope this would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

My solution is too too too slow, which is so slow that I can't stand it. But it does work when the group orders less than $20$. Such as the $D_8$ of order $16$

```
 DeleteDuplicatesBy[
  PermutationGroup /@ Subsets[GroupElements[DihedralGroup[8]]], 
  GroupElements] // Timing
```

> {169.313,{PermutationGroup[{}],PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{2,8},{3,7},{4,6}}]}],PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1,2},{3,8},{4,7},{5,6}}]}],PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}}]}],PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1,3},{4,8},{5,7}}]}],PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1,3,5,7},{2,4,6,8}}]}],PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1,4},{2,3},{5,8},{6,7}}]}],PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1,5},{2,4},{6,8}}]}],PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1,5},{2,6},{3,7},{4,8}}]}],PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1,6},{2,5},{3,4},{7,8}}]}],PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1,7},{2,6},{3,5}}]}],PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1,8},{2,7},{3,6},{4,5}}]}],PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{2,8},{3,7},{4,6}}],Cycles[{{1,2},{3,8},{4,7},{5,6}}]}],PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{2,8},{3,7},{4,6}}],Cycles[{{1,3},{4,8},{5,7}}]}],PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{2,8},{3,7},{4,6}}],Cycles[{{1,5},{2,4},{6,8}}]}],PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1,2},{3,8},{4,7},{5,6}}],Cycles[{{1,3,5,7},{2,4,6,8}}]}],PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1,2},{3,8},{4,7},{5,6}}],Cycles[{{1,5},{2,6},{3,7},{4,8}}]}],PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1,3},{4,8},{5,7}}],Cycles[{{1,5},{2,6},{3,7},{4,8}}]}],PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1,4},{2,3},{5,8},{6,7}}],Cycles[{{1,5},{2,6},{3,7},{4,8}}]}]}}

But this method obviously cannot get all subgroups of $S_4$, because I need to consider a combination of $2^{24}=16777216$ elements, which is unthinkable for me. There may be other specialized algorithms to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Some things change to better. In version 13 on Windows 10

```
FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup",  4},"Subgroups"]
```

> `{"Trivial", {"CyclicGroup", 2}, {"CyclicGroup", 3}, {"CyclicGroup",  4}, "Vierergruppe", {"SymmetricGroup", 3}, {"AlternatingGroup",  4}, {"SymmetricGroup", 4}}`

Comment: Note that this is only a subset of the subgroups, not all of them. :)

Comment: @yode: One may continue:`FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 3}, "Subgroups"]` which produces `{"Trivial", {"CyclicGroup", 2}, {"CyclicGroup", 3}, {"SymmetricGroup",
   3}}` and  `FiniteGroupData["Vierergruppe", "Subgroups"]` and `FiniteGroupData[{"AlternatingGroup", 4}, "Subgroups"]` and ... I leave the rest on your own.

Comment: Note all your subgroup of subgroups all in the subgroup list of $S_4$

Comment: @yode: No, it is not true : `FiniteGroupData[{"AlternatingGroup", 4}, "Subgroups"] ` results in `{"Trivial", {"CyclicGroup", 2}, {"CyclicGroup", 
  3}, {"AbelianGroup", {2, 2}}, {"AlternatingGroup", 4}}`.

Comment: `FiniteGroupData` returns a non-homogeneous group, but even if it is non-homogeneous, $S_4$ has 11 instead of 8 [as the maple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImOQO.png)

Comment: @yode So there is no way to get those with Mathematica? And no simple way to just list those?

Comment: For future readers of this comment: A dihedral group with group order 8 is missing in this list. For more information see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/285090/86543

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников as I understand, `FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 4}, "SubgroupElements"]` lists all subgroups.