# How to list all subgroups of symmetry group S_6?

Tags: permutation, group-theory

I learned from https://oeis.org/A005432 that $S_6$ has $1455$ subgroups, how can I list them all in mathematica?

As the comment says, the direct approach cannot solve the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listing all subgroups](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172981/listing-all-subgroups)

Comment: @Domen , yode's answer cannot even list the subgroups of $S_4$, I think we may need other methods.

Comment: Then please mention this in your question.

Comment: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_symmetric_group:S6 fails to list them. I think any (semi) brute force method is likely to fail. `FiniteGroupData[]` fails to list all `"Subgroups"` (just isomorphism classes are listed, I think), and `"SubgroupElements"`, which lists all subgroups in general, fails on $S_6$. -- Sage/GAP seems to be able to do it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191186/presentations-of-subgroups-of-s6-as-permutations

Comment: According to: https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/651 you can obtain all subgroups using `S := SymmetricGroup(6);
AllSubgroups(S);` on the online magma calculator http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/ but it truncates the results as it's too long

Comment: This answer also provides what might be an equivalent solution which will probably have the same problem https://mathoverflow.net/a/82881. Checking the number of occurences of the word "Permutation" in that list, there are 202 groups per request so you would have to truncate to about 202 results in the list and copy paste the results 8 times.

Comment: I know little about Magma but from a quick check of the (not clear) documentation https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/133 and asking ChatGPT, you can, for example. truncate to the last 200 elements of that list using `S:=SymmetricGroup(6);H:=AllSubgroups(S);H[#H-200..#H];` where #H is the length of the subgroup. If you are ok with just the conjugacy classes you can use Subgroups(S) (https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/690#8162, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3463728/could-we-use-magma-to-calculate-subgroups-of-a-fixed-order) instead of AllSubgroups(S)

Comment: Maybe one of the mathematica group packages at http://packagedata.net/ can do that. You can search for group in the search box

Comment: @MichaelE2 I am not sure FiniteGroupData is listing all the subgroups even up to conjugacy. For example, for $S_4$, `FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 4}, "Subgroups"] // Map[FiniteGroupData[#, "Order"] &]` does not show a subgroup of order 8. However there are dihedral subgroups of order 8 according to https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_symmetric_group:S4 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379841/how-to-enumerate-subgroups-of-each-order-of-s-4-by-hand. I also tried to compute all the subgroups conjugates and I found less than in SubgroupElements

Comment: @userrandrand Report it to WRI. I don't know about the limitations of `FiniteGroupData`. I imagine it was created in part by data entry and contains errors. $D_4$ shows up here: `FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 4}, "SylowSubgroups"]`. To the matter at hand: Is `FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 6}, "Subgroups"]` complete? Note that equivalences up to conjugacy, automorphism, and isomorphism are different. I think "Subgroups" (supposedly) gives isomorphism classes, but I don't know for a fact that is what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Group theory becomes somewhat scholastic  nowadays. For what purpose is  that list?

Answer (score 3):

**Purpose of this answer**: mainly to check whether `FiniteGroupData` is outputting correct results up to isomorphisms.

**TL;DR:**

- **The output of `FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 4}, "Subgroups"]`  is missing the dihedral group**.
- The distribution of group orders in `FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 6}, "Subgroups"]` seems correct although it could be a fluke as the output of `FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 6}, "Subgroups"]` seems to be removed of duplicates of isomorphisms (see text for further detail of how that makes a comparison with available data difficult)

---

I used the online magma calculator http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/ . The magma code first calculates all subgroups up to conjugation and then identifies each subgroup with a canonical reference group up to isomorphism.

I am not an expert in magma programming, I used a combination of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82873/using-magma-for-group-theory/82881#82881, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3324896/determine-subgroup-langle-12-1324-rangle-of-group-s-4, magma documentation and Phind which is a search engine that has GPT4 and where search results can be toggled on or off (sometimes I feel its better to ask its memory rather than rely on keyword searches)

**Note:** In the following : •=`\[Bullet]` and ⎵=`\[UnderBracket]`

### Verifying `FiniteGroupData` for $S_4$

It does not seem like the output of `FiniteGroupData` is complete. The dihedral group which is present in https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_symmetric_group:S4 and
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379841/how-to-enumerate-subgroups-of-each-order-of-s-4-by-hand is missing. The dihedral group is of order 8 whereas the other subgroups listed by `FiniteGroupData` are not as shown from the output of :

```
FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 4}, "Subgroups"] // Map[FiniteGroupData[#, "Order"] &]

(*{1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 12, 24}*)
```

This group is present in the output of the following Magma code that can be used in the online calculator. The results are presented in table format at the end of this section.

```
// Group definition
G := SymmetricGroup(4);

// Find all subgroups of G
subgroups := Subgroups(G);

// identify each subgroup
for S in subgroups do
    id := IdentifyGroup(S`subgroup);
    groupName := GroupName(SmallGroup(id[1], id[2]));
    print "SubGroup:\n";
    S`subgroup;
    "\n-\n\nIsomorphic to :\n";
    groupName;
    print "\n---\n";
end for;
```

I used Mathematica to rewrite the string as a table:

```
StringCases[magma⎵output, 
   "Order = " ~~ (a : DigitCharacter ..) ~~ 
     Shortest[___] ~~ ("Isomorphic to :

" ~~ Shortest[b__] ~~ "

---") :> {b, ToExpression@a}] // SortBy[Last] // 
 TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {None, {"SubGroup", "Order"}}] &
```

Output:

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{SubGroup} &
   \text{Order} \\
\hline
 \text{C1} & 1 \\
 \text{C2} & 2 \\
 \text{C2} & 2 \\
 \text{C3} & 3 \\
 \text{C2${}^{\wedge}$2} & 4
   \\
 \text{C2${}^{\wedge}$2} & 4
   \\
 \text{C4} & 4 \\
 \text{S3} & 6 \\
 \text{D4} & 8 \\
 \text{A4} & 12 \\
 \text{S4} & 24 \\
\end{array}
$$

The list is the same up to isomorphism as that of https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_symmetric_group:S4 .

Compare this result with that of `FiniteGroupData` :

```
FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 4}, "Subgroups"] // 
   Map[{#, FiniteGroupData[#, "Order"]} &] // 
  TableForm[#, 
    TableHeadings -> {None, {"Subgroup", "Order"}}] & // TeXForm
```

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{Subgroup} & \text{Order} \\
\hline
 \text{Trivial} & 1 \\
 \text{$\{$CyclicGroup, 2$\}$} & 2 \\
 \text{$\{$CyclicGroup, 3$\}$} & 3 \\
 \text{$\{$CyclicGroup, 4$\}$} & 4 \\
 \text{Vierergruppe} & 4 \\
 \text{$\{$SymmetricGroup, 3$\}$} & 6 \\
 \text{$\{$AlternatingGroup, 4$\}$} & 12 \\
 \text{$\{$SymmetricGroup, 4$\}$} & 24 \\
\end{array}
$$

Notice that:

- `FiniteGroupData` does not show duplicates of isomorphism groups.  I am not sure but this might make it difficult to reconstruct the permutation groups even with `FiniteGroupData[#, "PermutationGroupRepresentation"] &` as naively information seems to be removed by creating isomorphisms and deleting duplicates.
- $D_4$  which is a group of order 8 is missing in the output from `FiniteGroupData`. It is however present in `FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 4}, "SylowSubgroups"]` as mentioned in the comments.

### Verifying `FiniteGroupData` for $S_6$

The outputs are given at the end of this section but they are quite long. As a quick check, I removed the duplicate subgroups (notice that this is potentially a risk as some of the subgroups in the output of `FiniteGroupData` for $S_4$ were isomorphic to each other).  I sorted the orders in both lists and I checked that **the sorted lists of orders are the  same**

I got the following outputs :

#### `Magma` (with duplicates)

I used the same code with $S_6$. Changing the group in the magma code to `G := SymmetricGroup(6);`

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{SubGroup} &
   \text{Order} \\
\hline
 \text{C1} & 1 \\
 \text{C2} & 2 \\
 \text{C2} & 2 \\
 \text{C2} & 2 \\
 \text{C3} & 3 \\
 \text{C3} & 3 \\
 \text{C2${}^{\wedge}$2} & 4
   \\
 \text{C2${}^{\wedge}$2} & 4
   \\
 \text{C2${}^{\wedge}$2} & 4
   \\
 \text{C2${}^{\wedge}$2} & 4
   \\
 \text{C2${}^{\wedge}$2} & 4
   \\
 \text{C4} & 4 \\
 \text{C4} & 4 \\
 \text{C5} & 5 \\
 \text{C6} & 6 \\
 \text{C6} & 6 \\
 \text{S3} & 6 \\
 \text{S3} & 6 \\
 \text{S3} & 6 \\
 \text{S3} & 6 \\
 \text{C2${}^{\wedge}$3} & 8
   \\
 \text{C2${}^{\wedge}$3} & 8
   \\
 \text{C2*C4} & 8 \\
 \text{D4} & 8 \\
 \text{D4} & 8 \\
 \text{D4} & 8 \\
 \text{D4} & 8 \\
 \text{C3${}^{\wedge}$2} & 9
   \\
 \text{D5} & 10 \\
 \text{A4} & 12 \\
 \text{A4} & 12 \\
 \text{D6} & 12 \\
 \text{D6} & 12 \\
 \text{C2*D4} & 16 \\
 \text{C3*S3} & 18 \\
 \text{C3*S3} & 18 \\
 \text{C3:S3} & 18 \\
 \text{F5} & 20 \\
 \text{C2*A4} & 24 \\
 \text{C2*A4} & 24 \\
 \text{S4} & 24 \\
 \text{S4} & 24 \\
 \text{S4} & 24 \\
 \text{S4} & 24 \\
 \text{C3:S3.C2} & 36 \\
 \text{S3${}^{\wedge}$2} & 36
   \\
 \text{S3${}^{\wedge}$2} & 36
   \\
 \text{C2*S4} & 48 \\
 \text{C2*S4} & 48 \\
 \text{A5} & 60 \\
 \text{A5} & 60 \\
 \text{S3wrC2} & 72 \\
 \text{S5} & 120 \\
 \text{S5} & 120 \\
 \text{A6} & 360 \\
 \text{S6} & 720 \\
\end{array}
$$

#### `FiniteGroupData`+ Magma

In the code below, the `magma⎵output` is the string output from the magma calculator :

```
FiniteGroupData•SubGroups = 
  FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 6}, "Subgroups"];

orders = 
  FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 6}, "Subgroups"] // 
    Map[FiniteGroupData[#, "Order"] &] // Sort;

output = 
  StringCases[magma⎵output, 
    "Order = " ~~ (a : DigitCharacter ..) ~~ 
      Shortest[___] ~~ ("Isomorphic to :

" ~~ Shortest[b__] ~~ "

---") :> {b, ToExpression@a}] // SortBy[Last];

magma⎵subgroups = 
  output // DeleteDuplicatesBy[First] // Map[First];
{FiniteGroupData\[Bullet]SubGroups, magma\[UnderBracket]subgroups, 
   orders} // Transpose // TableForm
```

**The output is wide the reader might need to use the horizontal scroll at the bottom.**

**NOTE that the table is only sorted by group order, the subgroups between the output of Magma and that of Mathematica do not necessarily correspond on each line.**

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{FiniteGroupData} & \text{Magma} & \text{Order} \\
\hline
 \text{Trivial} & \text{C1} & 1 \\
 \text{$\{$CyclicGroup, 2$\}$} & \text{C2} & 2 \\
 \text{$\{$CyclicGroup, 3$\}$} & \text{C3} & 3 \\
 \text{$\{$CyclicGroup, 4$\}$} & \text{C2${}^{\wedge}$2} & 4 \\
 \text{Vierergruppe} & \text{C4} & 4 \\
 \text{$\{$CyclicGroup, 5$\}$} & \text{C5} & 5 \\
 \text{$\{$CyclicGroup, 6$\}$} & \text{C6} & 6 \\
 \text{$\{$AbelianGroup, $\{$2, 2, 2$\}\}$} & \text{S3} & 6 \\
 \text{$\{$AbelianGroup, $\{$4, 2$\}\}$} & \text{C2${}^{\wedge}$3} & 8
   \\
 \text{$\{$SymmetricGroup, 3$\}$} & \text{C2*C4} & 8 \\
 \text{$\{$DihedralGroup, 4$\}$} & \text{D4} & 8 \\
 \text{$\{$AbelianGroup, $\{$3, 3$\}\}$} & \text{C3${}^{\wedge}$2} & 9
   \\
 \text{$\{$DihedralGroup, 5$\}$} & \text{D5} & 10 \\
 \text{$\{$DihedralGroup, 6$\}$} & \text{A4} & 12 \\
 \text{$\{$AlternatingGroup, 4$\}$} & \text{D6} & 12 \\
 \text{$\{$DirectProduct, $\{\{$CyclicGroup, 2$\}$, $\{$DihedralGroup,
   4$\}\}\}$} & \text{C2*D4} & 16 \\
 \text{$\{$SemidirectProduct, $\{\{$CyclicGroup, 2$\}$,
   $\{$AbelianGroup, $\{$3, 3$\}\}\}\}$} & \text{C3*S3} & 18 \\
 \text{$\{$DirectProduct, $\{\{$CyclicGroup, 3$\}$, $\{$SymmetricGroup,
   3$\}\}\}$} & \text{C3:S3} & 18 \\
 \text{$\{$SemidirectProduct, $\{\{$CyclicGroup, 4$\}$, $\{$CyclicGroup,
   5$\}\}\}$} & \text{F5} & 20 \\
 \text{$\{$DirectProduct, $\{\{$CyclicGroup, 2$\}$,
   $\{$AlternatingGroup, 4$\}\}\}$} & \text{C2*A4} & 24 \\
 \text{$\{$SymmetricGroup, 4$\}$} & \text{S4} & 24 \\
 \text{$\{$DirectProduct, $\{\{$SymmetricGroup, 3$\}$,
   $\{$SymmetricGroup, 3$\}\}\}$} & \text{C3:S3.C2} & 36 \\
 \text{$\{$SemidirectProduct, $\{\{$CyclicGroup, 4$\}$,
   $\{$AbelianGroup, $\{$3, 3$\}\}\}\}$} & \text{S3${}^{\wedge}$2} & 36
   \\
 \text{$\{$DirectProduct, $\{\{$CyclicGroup, 2$\}$, $\{$SymmetricGroup,
   4$\}\}\}$} & \text{C2*S4} & 48 \\
 \text{$\{$AlternatingGroup, 5$\}$} & \text{A5} & 60 \\
 \text{$\{$SemidirectProduct, $\{\{$CyclicGroup, 2$\}$,
   $\{$DirectProduct, $\{\{$SymmetricGroup, 3$\}$, $\{$SymmetricGroup,
   3$\}\}\}\}\}$} & \text{S3wrC2} & 72 \\
 \text{$\{$SymmetricGroup, 5$\}$} & \text{S5} & 120 \\
 \text{$\{$AlternatingGroup, 6$\}$} & \text{A6} & 360 \\
 \text{$\{$SymmetricGroup, 6$\}$} & \text{S6} & 720 \\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 2):

You can install [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org) and parse the output:

```
gapsubgroups = RunProcess[
    {"/Applications/gap-4.12.2/gap", "-q"}, (* change loc as needed *)
    "StandardOutput",
    "AllSubgroups(SymmetricGroup(6));"];

subgroups = gapsubgroups // (* ad hoc parsing -- sorry *)
       StringReplace[#, "(())" -> "{Cycles@{}}"] & //
      StringReplace[#, {"[" -> "{", "]" -> "}", 
         "(" ~~ c : ("," | DigitCharacter) ... ~~ ")" :> 
          "cyc[" <> c <> "]"}] & //
     StringReplace[#, "Group" -> "PermutationGroup@"] & //
    ToExpression //
   ReplaceAll[{c : Verbatim[Times][__cyc] :> 
      Cycles[List @@ c /. cyc -> List], c_cyc :> Cycles[{List @@ c}]}];
```

Checks:

```
Length[subgroups]
(*  1455  *)

GroupOrder /@ subgroups //
  Counts //
 BarChart[#, ChartLabels -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 500] &
```

[image]

Comment: As documentation says "For users of Windows 10, we strongly recommend using GAP via the Windows Subsystem for Linux", As far as I understand it, this installation  is programming aerobatics.

Comment: It could have maybe been interesting to sort the subgroups by their order to see if there is some sort of scaling law for large groups

Comment: @userrandrand I think the subgroup list produced by GAP is ordered by order.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry I might have misunderstood the y-axis and even then my comment did not make sense, never mind. I posted as an answer some computations with the online magma calculator and found that the distribution of orders, up to isomorphism, seems to be the same as in `FiniteGroupData`.

Comment: @user64494 Windows has stack memory that expands into heap, Linux does not allow it. WSL v1 and Windows give one default float registry state, Linux another. And finally, glibc math.h is more accurate than AMD's fork of the math library that is used on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In 13.2.1 on Windows 10

```
 FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 6}, "Subgroups"]
```

> `{Trivial,{CyclicGroup,2},{CyclicGroup,3},{CyclicGroup,4},Vierergruppe,{CyclicGroup,5},{CyclicGroup,6},{AbelianGroup,{2,2,2}},{AbelianGroup,{4,2}},{SymmetricGroup,3},{DihedralGroup,4},{AbelianGroup,{3,3}},{DihedralGroup,5},{DihedralGroup,6},{AlternatingGroup,4},{DirectProduct,{{CyclicGroup,2},{DihedralGroup,4}}},{SemidirectProduct,{{CyclicGroup,2},{AbelianGroup,{3,3}}}},{DirectProduct,{{CyclicGroup,3},{SymmetricGroup,3}}},{SemidirectProduct,{{CyclicGroup,4},{CyclicGroup,5}}},{DirectProduct,{{CyclicGroup,2},{AlternatingGroup,4}}},{SymmetricGroup,4},{DirectProduct,{{SymmetricGroup,3},{SymmetricGroup,3}}},{SemidirectProduct,{{CyclicGroup,4},{AbelianGroup,{3,3}}}},{DirectProduct,{{CyclicGroup,2},{SymmetricGroup,4}}},{AlternatingGroup,5},{SemidirectProduct,{{CyclicGroup,2},{DirectProduct,{{SymmetricGroup,3},{SymmetricGroup,3}}}}},{SymmetricGroup,5},{AlternatingGroup,6},{SymmetricGroup,6}}`

and then, for example,

```
FiniteGroupData[{"DihedralGroup", 6}, "Subgroups"]
```

> `{"Trivial", {"CyclicGroup", 2}, {"CyclicGroup", 3}, {"CyclicGroup",  6}, {"DihedralGroup", 2}, {"DihedralGroup", 3}, {"DihedralGroup",  6}}`

and so on.

Comment: As it was pointed to you in [your previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/268647/75628), this does not list _all_ of the subgroups.

Comment: @Domen: Please, ground your claim.  What subgroup of $S_6$ cannot be obtained in such a way?

Comment: I don't see 1455 subgroups listed in your answer. Please, ground your claim that there are not 1455 subgroups.

Comment: I am not sure how trustworthy FiniteGroupData is. For example, For $S_4$, `FiniteGroupData[{"SymmetricGroup", 4}, "Subgroups"] // Map[FiniteGroupData[#, "Order"] &]` does not show a subgroup of order 8. However there are dihedral subgroups of order 8 according to https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_symmetric_group:S4 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379841/how-to-enumerate-subgroups-of-each-order-of-s-4-by-hand